# Git bug while trying to add or commit

Tags: git, github

Suddenly encountered a strange error

`error: BUG: switch 'n' (--dry-run) invalid short name`

Everything was working fine for me yesterday. Today, all I did was start a separate folder for configs and utilities. And when I tried to commit I got this error. Also now git on other projects gives the same error. I have no idea what it is. Googling hasn't led me to an answer yet.

I tried to commit from git bash and PyCharm. I also tried deleting this entire project altogether, but other projects still give this error. I had absolutely nothing to do with the git itself, and all I did was only change the code in a few files, and also just created a folder where I put a few old files

I do not know what else I can describe, but if something is needed, I will edit this post

Comment: Please show us the complete command you're trying to run. Also check if you have any git aliases defined. And [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Which git command were you executing when you got that error? Also, which git version do you have installed? You can run `git version` to find the version number.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i tried to "git add ." and also tried to add any single file. Also tbh idk about git aliases, all what i do everytime is just creating a repo, "add ." then just "git commit" and "git push origin master". Nothing more

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen trying to "git add ." and also with single files.

Version is -  git version 2.32.0.windows.2

Comment: Please provide the actual command you ran along with its output.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen 
`$ git add .`
`error: BUG: switch 'n' (--dry-run) invalid short name`

And

`$git add main.py`
`error: BUG: switch 'n' (--dry-run) invalid short name`

Comment: I can't see anything in the release notes from versions coming after 2.32.0 but you might want to update to the latest version anyway, on the off chance that there is a corner case bug in the one you have. The latest Windows version of git is 2.35.1.windows.2.

Comment: Also, check your .gitconfig file in your user folder, that it hasn't become corrupted or whatnot. You can find it by hitting Win+R and typing in `%USERPROFILE%` and hitting enter, or opening it directly in notepad: `NOTEPAD %USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Many thanks! Updating to the latest version helped and now the commands work without bugs

Comment: Glad to hear it. I'm hesitant to leave an answer though as we still don't know the root cause. If you want to self-answer with what you did then please go ahead. I feel it is slightly better that you that had the problem then also answers it with "I updated git and the problem went away" rather than me providing an answer that says "You should update git and the problem goes away". Next person visiting here might not be so lucky, but this solved it for you.

Comment: Also, in the future, add such things as git commands and stuff to the question itself. Comments should be more like requests for clarification and so on, but the actual clarification should go in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating git version solved a problem.